# Finding a list of words in a corpus using NLTK? Cannot find the frequency of words

Tags: python, nltk

I have downloaded a corpus and tokenised the words. I have a list of the main characters and I want to find out how many times each name appears in the corpus. I have tried using a frequency function with a dictionary but I don't know how to get the name count..

```
target_url0 = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/135/135-0.txt'
book_raw = urlopen(target_url0).read().decode('utf-8')
word_tokens = word_tokenize(book_raw)

character_list = ['Myriel','Bishop','Baptistine','Magloire','Cravatte','Valjean','Gervais','Fantine','Tholomyès'
                  ,'Blachevelle','Dahlia','Fameuil','Favourite','Listolier','Zéphine','Cosette','Thénardier',
                  'Éponine','Azelma','Javert','Fauchelevent','Bamatabois','Champmathieu',
                  'Brevet','Simplice','Chenildieu','Cochepaille','Innocente','Reverend','Ascension','Crucifixion',
                  'Gavroche','Magnon',
                  'Gillenormand','Marius','Colonel','Mabeuf','Enjolras','Combeferre','Prouvaire',
                 'Feuilly','Courfeyrac','Bahorel','Lesgle','Joly','Grantaire','Patron-Minette','Brujon',
                 'Toussaint'] 


fdist_mis = FreqDist(word_tokens)

filtered_word_freq = dict((character_list, freq) for character_list, freq in fdist_mis.items())
```

When I explore filtered_word_freqt, it just returns all of the word tokens instead of a dictionary of the unique characters and their occurrences. Any help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you like to see the frequency? You can get a count of # times each word was seen or a ratio of how often within the total text or even a fancy formatted table. Relevant functions copied from [here](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/nltk.FreqDist):

```
N()[source]
Return the total number of sample outcomes that have been recorded by this FreqDist. For the number of unique sample values (or bins) with counts greater than zero, use FreqDist.B().
Return type:    int

freq(sample)[source]
Return the frequency of a given sample. The frequency of a sample is defined as the count of that sample divided by the total number of sample outcomes that have been recorded by this FreqDist. The count of a sample is defined as the number of times that sample outcome was recorded by this FreqDist. Frequencies are always real numbers in the range [0, 1].

tabulate(*args, **kwargs)[source]
Tabulate the given samples from the frequency distribution (cumulative), displaying the most frequent sample first. If an integer parameter is supplied, stop after this many samples have been plotted.
Parameters: samples (list) – The samples to plot (default is all samples)
```

Here's my version of your code (including the using statements and fully qualified calls for future readers):

```
import urllib.request
import nltk
nltk.download("punkt")

target_url0 = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/135/135-0.txt'
book_raw = urllib.request.urlopen(target_url0).read().decode('utf-8')
word_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(book_raw)

character_list = ['Myriel','Bishop','Baptistine','Magloire','Cravatte','Valjean','Gervais','Fantine','Tholomyès','Blachevelle','Dahlia','Fameuil','Favourite','Listolier','Zéphine','Cosette','Thénardier','Éponine','Azelma','Javert','Fauchelevent','Bamatabois','Champmathieu','Brevet','Simplice','Chenildieu','Cochepaille','Innocente','Reverend','Ascension','Crucifixion','Gavroche','Magnon','Gillenormand','Marius','Colonel','Mabeuf','Enjolras','Combeferre','Prouvaire','Feuilly','Courfeyrac','Bahorel','Lesgle','Joly','Grantaire','Patron-Minette','Brujon','Toussaint'] 
fdist_mis = nltk.FreqDist(word_tokens)
```

Then I can use that dictionary to get the frequency for any word. E.g.

```
.
>>> fdist_mis["Myriel"]
28
>>> fdist_mis["Bishop"]
260
```

Comment: I believe the former: I would like to see the total amount of times the word has occurred. How would I implement this into my code?

Comment: You can post your whole code if you like, but from what I can see above, you should be happy with "fdist_mis['Myriel']" 


In the above, all that the last line does is restrict the dictionary to the characters you care about. Accessing either should give you the number.

Comment: I have updated my post with the full code, thanks again for your help. Bizarrely I cannot find any of the names in the text using your method!

Comment: Edited to add fully qualified import statements and show how to use the dictionary. Hope that helps.